# Counting Sort stuck in for loop

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to write a Counting sort function but for some reason it's getting stuck inside my first for loop. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my logic? I'm new to C++ so please explain any answers so that I may learn. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I only get the problem(window pop-up saying "CountSort.exe has stopped working") only when I input a `maxInt` less than 130,000. If I input any number higher than that it works great. The list of numbers I want to sort is from an external .txt file that I read. The numbers are: 1 4 6 2 34 65 2 3 64 2 12 97 56 45 3 43 23 99 2

```
struct CalcMaxInt
{
    int maxInt;
    CalcMaxInt () : maxInt(0) {}
    void operator () (int i) { if (i > maxInt) maxInt = i; }
};

void countSort(vector<int> &numbers)
{
    CalcMaxInt cmi = std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), CalcMaxInt());
    int maxInt = cmi.maxInt + 1;

    vector <int> temp1(maxInt);
    vector <int> temp2(maxInt);
    int min = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
  {
      temp2[numbers[i]] = temp2[numbers[i]] + 1;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= maxInt; i++)
  {
      temp2[i] = temp2[i] + temp2[i - 1];
  }

  for (int i = numbers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
      temp1[temp2[numbers[i]] - 1] = numbers[i];
      temp2[numbers[i]] = temp2[numbers[i]] -1;
  }

   for (int i =0;i<numbers.size();i++)
   {
       numbers[i]=temp1[i];
   }
   return;
}
```

Comment: Which inputs demonstrate the problem?

Comment: When you dereference `temp2[0]` before you've set a value, what does it do? Blow up? Give you a default value?...

Comment: It blows up only if I input a `maxInt` less than 130,000.  I would like it to work for any number that is passed in since it is inputed by the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't looked for algorithmic errors, but the temp vectors should be sized up, and initialized to `0` (this is just for paranoia, the default initializer for `int` should be `0`).

```
vector<int> temp1(maxInt, 0);
vector<int> temp2(maxInt, 0);
```

After fixing that, the program seems to run on my system, correctly sorting a reverse sorted array. But, you should test with a more complete set of test cases.

Because of the way counting sort works, the `maxInt` parameter needs to be a value at least one larger than the largest value held by the input array.

You could modify the function to make a pass over the vector to locate the largest.

```
struct CalcMaxInt {
    int maxInt;
    CalcMaxInt () : maxInt(0) {}
    void operator () (int i) { if (i > maxInt) maxInt = i; }
};

CalcMaxInt cmi = std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), CalcMaxInt());
int maxInt = cmi.maxInt + 1;
```

Then, you wouldn't have to pass it in.

You might want to add some code to print out what you read in for your input, so that you are sure it is what you think it ought to be.

Comment: For me it seems to only work if `maxInt` is 130,000 or greater.

Comment: @Fourthmeal70: If you want to debug a particular test case, you need to include a test case that exhibits the problem. At the very least describe the input that is giving you problems in your question. Regards.

Comment: I edited my question with some more details. I don't have a large list as you can see, and there aren't any large numbers either. So I assume I should be able to input `maxInt` of 100 in my case and be ok. But my program doesn't like it.

Comment: Yes I added the `CalcMaxInt` to my code and it runs through and sorts like it should, prints the sorted vector and then still pops up with the error. 

I am printing both sorted and unsorted vectors in the `main()` function so I'm sure of the values that are being read. I edited my code above to reflect the changes.

Comment: Yes you are right. You've answered my initial question. Thanks.